# What happened to the crew and guards of the Tantive IV?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In *Star Wars: A New Hope*, we see a number of [Alderaanian consular guards](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Alderaanian_consular_security) that were on the Tantive IV being escorted away by Stormtroopers. **But what was the fate of these guards and the crew of the ship?**

I dived into Wookieepedia and found that one of the guards, [Gale Torg](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gale_Torg) was one of those guards that were on the [Tantive IV](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tantive_IV) (he is listed as a crew member); He was then present at the awards ceremony on Yavin 4 as one of the [Honor Guards](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_Honor_Guard). This suggests to me that he either was captured and escaped or managed to flee at some point.

Comment: Seems like a great fan fiction opportunity.

Comment: Wookiepedia appears to contain a factual error. Gale Torg wasn't on the Tantive IV in the film Rogue One, he was on Yavin IV the entire time providing base security.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **The ship**

**Survived and lived to fight another day.**

We learn in the [Rise of Skywalker: Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) that the Tantive IV survived. With the dissolution of the Senate and the new-found power of the Empire, getting rid of all of the evidence of an attack on a Senatorial vessel was suddenly of far less importance and it just got forgotten.

> The Tantive IV was the historic Alderaanian consular ship that shuttled the Death Star plans away from Scarif after the Rebel Alliance's first victory. A faulty hyperdrive subsystem allowed the Empire to track and intercept it over Tatooine. The captured Tantive IV was scheduled to be destroyed as part of a falsified report to the Senate, but **the Senate was disbanded within days and the ship's destruction was no longer a priority.**

Eventually it made its way back into Leia's possession.

> Leia has recently been reunited with her consular ship from her teen years, which was discovered moldering in a hangar in the Yarma system by a sympathetic former Imperial senator. It was returned as a gift.

### The Crew

**All killed.**

According to the (canon) *[Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)* factbook, the crewmen and officers that survived the initial assault were executed by the Empire.

> **Bitter End**: In an attempt to contain any leaks about the Death Star,
> **all of the rebel survivors were executed** and the Tantive IV was
> flagged for disposal. After Alderaan was destroyed the ship was no
> longer a priority and was forgotten.

---

<s>According to the fully canon [Star Wars: Ships of the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Ships_of_the_Galaxy), the Tantive IV was destroyed by the Empire shortly after being captured. Given that none of the crew were able to be coerced into revealing the location of the Rebel base on Yavin, it's likely that the majority of its *senior* crew were killed during the boarding process and the rest of the crew were on board the ship when it was destroyed.</s>

[image: scan from Star Wars: Ships of the Galaxy]

Comment: Hopefully the ship's maximum speed of "950 kph" is measured in something other than kilometers per hour. That'd take weeks to get from Earth's surface to its Moon, let alone any sort of interplanetary journey…

Comment: @duskwuff - Definitely kilometres per hour. It's [explicitly stated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh0zW.png) earlier in the book. These are, of course, in-atmosphere speeds, not sublight

Answer (score 21):

They were most likely killed <s>and the Tantive IV was destroyed</s>. The case for this is

1. Vader's plan is to make it look like some sort of accident to reassure the Senate

   > VADER: Leave that to me. Send a distress signal and then inform the senate                      that all aboard were killed!
2. Anyone else believed to have even had a chance to access the Death Star plans was also killed (i.e. the Jawas, Owen and Beru Lars)
3. Leia never saw any others from the ship during her time in captivity

   > I survived as a prisoner, first aboard Vader's Star Destroyer and then aboard the Death Star. I never learned the fates of the others.
   > <sup><sub>Leia, [The Rebel Files](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rebel_Files)</sub></sup>

So how come Gale Torg is listed as a Tantive IV crew member but shows up on Yavin IV? The only logical explanation is that they're listing any named crew members who ever served aboard the ship during her entire history. So Gale Torg (given his close connections to Leia) probably served aboard the Tantive IV at some point, but was not there on the day she met up with Vader.

**NOTE** - Originally it was implied (and even stated in canon) that the Tantive IV was destroyed. *The Rise of Skywalker* [retconned that so the ship itself was not destroyed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192834/62709) by Vader.

Answer (score 0):

It's now confirmed that during the Battle of Exegol in Episode IX, the Tantive IV was struck by Sidious' lightning and was unable to regain control, destroying the ship. Nien Numb was piloting it and was killed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Despite the previous answer, the question is actually asking about the personnel onboard, not the ship itself.